# CakePHP - Missing Database Table

Tags: apache, cakephp

So I've got my server running on local machine. Everything is working there and I just wanted to extend the possibility of the server by adding an Agency model.
Then I put all of the files to the dev server, to make it available online - and when I try to go to "agencies" (domain.com/agencies/) - Missing Database Table Error shows up.

Everything works fine on my computer.
I've checked 5 times if all of the names in the database are correct.
I've checked the database.cfg in the cakephp but it must be good - everything else is working there.

Please help!

### Update

Clearing models cache didn't help

### Here is the code of the model:

```
<?php
class Agency extends AppModel{
var $name = 'Agency';

var $validate = array(
    'id' => array(
        'blank' => array(
            'rule' => array('blank'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'company' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'website_url' => array(
        'url' => array(
            'rule' => array('url'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'status' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'profession_id' => array(
        'multiple' => array(
            'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
            'message' => 'Please select at least 1 profession',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'seniority_id' => array(
        'multiple' => array(
            'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'industry_id' => array(
        'multiple' => array(
            'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'sector_id' => array(
        'multiple' => array(
            'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'zone_id' => array(
        'multiple' => array(
            'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'size' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    )
);

var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Profession' => array(
        'className' => 'Profession',
        'joinTable' => 'agencies_professions',
        'foreignKey' => 'agency_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'profession_id',
        'unique' => true,
        //'conditions' => '',
        //'fields' => '',
        //'order' => ''
    ),
    'Seniority' => array(
        'className' => 'Seniority',
        'joinTable' => 'agencies_seniorities',
        'foreignKey' => 'agency_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'seniority_id',
        'unique' => true,
        //'conditions' => '',
        //'fields' => '',
        //'order' => ''
    ),
    'Industry' => array(
        'className' => 'Industry',
        'joinTable' => 'agencies_industries',
        'foreignKey' => 'agency_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'industry_id',
        'unique' => true,
        //'conditions' => '',
        //'fields' => '',
        //'order' => ''
    ),
    'Sector' => array(
        'className' => 'Sector',
        'joinTable' => 'agencies_sectors',
        'foreignKey' => 'agency_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'sector_id',
        'unique' => true,
        //'conditions' => '',
        //'fields' => '',
        //'order' => ''
    ),
    'Zone' => array(
        'className' => 'Zone',
        'joinTable' => 'agencies_zones',
        'foreignKey' => 'agency_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'zone_id',
        'unique' => true,
        //'conditions' => '',
        //'fields' => '',
        //'order' => ''
    )
);

 var $hasMany= array(
    'Office' => array(
        'className' => 'Office',
        'foreignKey' => 'office_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
 );
}
```

### Update

The debug was set to 2 from the very beginning because it is a dev server.

### Update

It is not a matter of lower/upper case names.

Comment: Do you have an "agencies" table in your database?

Comment: If the agencies table does exist; try clearing your model cache located at `APP/tmp/cache/models` - that often clears up strange behaviour

Comment: Yes I do have this table in my database. I did clear model cache too :) Nothing solves the problem.

Comment: post the exact message; I (guess) you have created `AgenciesController`, `Agency` model and the appropriate views?

Comment: Ofcourse I did - here is the message: Missing Database Table

Error: Database table agencies for model Agency was not found.

Comment: maybe it's a lower/upper case problem on the table names

Comment: No - I checked the names 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The database I was adding new tables was not the one connected to the dev server, but to the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make any changes to your database, please make sure that your app/config/core.php file debug value is 2. `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

If it is 0 database changes will not be detected.

This is because in production Cake caches the database structure so that it doesn't have to query the db again at every page load. This is rarely a problem because you should develop with debug level set to 2 anyway.

So whenever you change your database just make it 2 once.

Comment: In the app/config/core.php file it is already set to Configure::write('debug', 2);